# Laravel Eloquent Query Builder (Using query existence, using whereHas)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

**Tables**

```
PROFILE
id    address    type    approved    fky_profile_vendor_id

VENDOR
id    name

PRODUCT
id    name    price    instock    fky_prod_vendor_id
```

**Relationship**

```
PROFILE <-(one-to-one)-> VENDOR <- (one-to-many) -> PRODUCT
```

**Query**

Eloquent query to get all the products those are in stock

```
PRODUCT::where('instock','>',0)->get();
```

How can I get all the products in stock of a approved vendor?

Thanks

K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**App\Profile**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model {

    public function scopeApproved($query)
    {
        return $query->where('approved', 'y');
    }

    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\\Vendor');
    }

}
```

--

**App\Vendor**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vendor extends Model {

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\\Profile');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\\Product');
    }

}
```

--

**App\Product**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {

    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\\Vendor');
    }

}
```

---

**How to use:**

```
$vendors = Vendor::whereHas('profile', function ($q) { $q->approved(); })->with('products')->get();

$products = $vendors->map(function ($vendor)
{
    return $vendor->products;
});
```

This will return a `Collection` of `Products`s of `Vendor`s with approved `Profile`.

Comment: I need all Products (instock > 0) for only from Vendors with approved Profile ( approved='y')

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but this went completely over me, I request you to explain 'How to use' section a bit more, especially `->approved()` and `->map`.

Comment: `->approved` method is the `scopeApproved` in `Profile` and it's basically just an alias for `->where('approved', 'y')`.

`map` is just a fluent method to go through each of the `$vendors` array (`Collection` actually). It's basically the same as `foreach ($vendors as $vendor)`

What that whole code do is, it fetches all of the `Vendor`s with an approved profile *on the first line*. And goes through each of the vendor and add its products to `$products` array *on the second line and the rest*.

Comment: Also to get the `Product`s with *instock > 0*, you need to change `$vendor->products` as `$vendor->products->filter(function ($product) { return $product->instock > 0; })`